# Simultaneous Java and Scala development within the same project

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, scala

I want to leverage the Scala's Actor Framework while I develop the user interface in the familiar Swing way.

Is it possible to have a mixed Java - Scala project in Eclipse, NetBeans or any other IDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intellij does a good job of supporting mixed Java / Scala projects. At the moment the Scala support in Intellij seems better to me than the Scala IDE for Eclipse. (I have been a long time Eclipse user, recently trying Intellij on the recommendation of some other Scala coders).

Comment: Yes, the co-development works. In scala mode I can see the javadoc. Unfortunately in java mode asking javadoc on a scala item shows an error message.

Comment: Although skaffman gave an equivalently good answer I choose this one as the Intellij does seemingly a better job. Thank you.
It wasn't an easy decision as I'm not familiar with Intellij. However, for the sake of my task I'll have to learn it too.

Comment: +1 to IntelliJ having better Scala support than Eclipse.

Answer (score 21):

The "official" Scala plugin for Eclipse allows you to add the "scala nature" to any project, alongside the java nature. This allows you to mix and match however you'd wish.

I was playing with scala for the first time last night, using the Eclipse IDE, and it works very well.

---

Also, I just ran across this article: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/joint-compilation-of-scala-and-java-sources

Seems that scalac knows enough about java to be able to resolve dependencies on java source, without actually compiling them. Very smart.

Comment: Nice. Does this cooperation work for the javadoc / scaladoc in both direction?

Comment: That's a good question. I suspect not. If there are circular dependencies between java and scala, it might get awkward. That could be a real issue for continuous integration systems.

Comment: Thank you. It truly works. Unfortunately, the plugin itself is not that advanced as its Intellij counterpart. Although I very much love the Eclipse way of java development, I would rather use Intellij for this particular mixed task. +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Mixing JAVA (Netbeans GUI-Builder) and Scala-Swing:**

I just created a new JPanel with the GUI-Builder and some controls and simple logic.

Then created a scala object like seen in Scala-Swing tutorials:

```
object MySampleView extends Frame { title = "SomeTitle" ...
```

Then i added the new JPanel to the contents:

```
   contents = new Component { override lazy val peer = new MySampleJPanel() }
```

When compiling the project i see every change of the JPanel in GUI-Builder Cool.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Scala's Swing wrapper? It's very lightweight in the sense that you've always access to the underlying Swing classes but it's very well thought out. I've found it pleasant to work with - the *reactions* pattern makes event handling so much easier and the actor framework makes event propagation *so much clearer than using PropertyChangeSupport*

It's perfectly possible to use it with your own custom Swing widgets too.

Comment: I tried the sample programs from the Scala book but I found it too different from my years long Swing GUI development experience.

Comment: I've been coding Swing for 10 years - give Scala a chance!

Comment: I think it will be enough to learn the scala way of programming and the actor framework, and avoid confusions due the Scala GUI development practice differences as I'm working on several other, Swing GUI-ed projects at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully mixed Java and Scala in my app. It runs in the Goggle App Engine and I use Spring MVC for the UI. (will port to Lift later)

The plugins for Intellij are a great help. Though it is still early days and there are occasional problems. (for instance the Scala plugin compiler does not seem to like JDO enhanced Java classes too much...there is a work around and I am sure this bug will be fixed soon).

The only thing I find a bit tedious about the mix is dealing with Java APIs that return Java collection class in Scala. Its very clunky and you have to jump through hoops a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The [Scala plugins for NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Scala) are doing well too. With Swing development made so easy with NetBeans, it might just be what you are looking for :)

Comment: Yes, this was one of the meaning of "the familiar Swing way", as not to code manually, but use a GUI builder. But I wasn't sure before, if the actual hybrid project would be possible. Thanks. (I knew Scala for Eclipse but it was a bit disappointing - even the syntax highlight wasn't working correctly/instantly as in Java.) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Great!!! Thank you for sharing the idea.

Just to complement, the code below made use of a GUI editor (I'm using WindowBuilder + Eclipse + Scala Plugin) to design the GUI and then everything else can be done using Scala. Now it's possible to use a Java Swing GUI editor and do all the programming in Scala.

```
import swing._
import event._
object TestApp extends Frame {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    title = "Scala Swing Test App"
    val gui = new MyTestPanel() // a JPanel class from the GUI Editor
    val button = new Button {override lazy val peer = gui.getBtnMyButton()}
            // getBtnMyButton() is generated in the Gui Editor (Expose Component)
    contents = new Component{ override lazy val peer = gui }
    this.listenTo(button)
    reactions += {
        case ButtonClicked(b) => println("BUTTON CLICK.")
    }
    this.visible = true
} }
```

Mvackel